# Symfony 2 forms -- make an array to be serialized on the database?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I make a Symfony 2 form so that a particular field is serialized on the database?

The client side will send an array for the field `foo`, which is `VARCHAR` in the database. I want the `foo` be ran through `serialize()`, but I don't know how to do that, because all I do is:

```
$form->bind($request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)